# Build fails for Kivy app in Xcode - can't open file 'generate-ios-source-and-headers.py'

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivy

I am trying to test a Kivy app on my iPhone, but when I try building it, I get the following error...

```
/usr/bin/python: can't open file 'generate-ios-source-and-headers.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

According to the error, this happens when trying to run custom shell script 'Generate Source and Headers'. This script contains the following...

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/python generate-ios-source-and-headers.py
```

I followed the instructions [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html), which uses kivy-ios to create an xcode project for the kivy app. The missing file, 'generate-ios-source-and-headers.py', is in my kivy-ios package (kivy-ios > tmp > libffi-3.0.13 ), but for some reason when Xcode builds the app, that file is not found.

I've made sure my homebrew is updated and I think I've properly configured the xcode build settings.

How do I fix this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove symlinks before running the first Xcode build, by running this command in the kivy-ios folder

```
find ./ -type l -exec rm {} \;
```

Also, after every failed Xcode build, the YourApp folder needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the relation between Xcode and this error. When Xcode build the app, it has nothing to compile from the distribution, because you compile the whole thing before with `tools/build-all.sh`.

Xcode is just executing our script to fetch your application source and package it, and compile the main.m.

I guess your Xcode project is corrupted somehow, and include invalid steps. It would be nice to debug it. Feel free to share your xcodeproj :)